# Best way to get all elements by attribute name part

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have `data-min-checkbox` and `data-min-select` attributes.

How can I select both elements matching data-min with construction like `$([data-min-*])`?

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-min-checkbox],[data-min-select]")
```

Think CSS selectors for the win

Comment: there are lots of such attributes, near 10. So I search for a way to use something like :contains with attribute name

Comment: If you can do it with CSS, you can do it with querySelectorAll (or jQueery if you must) ... I don't know of a CSS selector syntax that allows wildcards in the parameter name, so I've answered your question to the best of my abilities